# One IOS App, 3 countries domain using 3 different Data bases

Tags: ios, build, bundle, countries

We already have `E commerce` app Targeting 3 different countries with 3 different domains. It also uses 3 different DB.

Now we are going for `IOS` app. So my questions here are:

1. Can we upload a `bundle` for specific country only? (Available in that country only, if multiple `bundles` allowed for single app)
2. Should we handle `JSON` based DB request in a single bundle by checking user's location? (so single bundle handled by programming)

Our goal is here our app will allow only specific country's user to place order.
Also prices are different for different countries, prices are from server.
We don't have in app purchase prices.

Please let me know what option is best. Even if new please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Its a broad question with lots of good answers and unfortunately all of them are opinion based but I will give my two cents.

- You can absolutely create multiple apps and target a specific country. You control this by changing the availability preference. (see pic) This will allow the app to be shown only in a certain country.
- The advantage of this method is that you can have complete control & customizability specific to a country.
- The disadvantage is that you are now maintaining multiple code bases. If you have a code bug in one app then you need to update 3 apps to fix the "same" bug. What if you want to support more countries. Now you have to create that many clones of the app. Think about if you had to add a new feature. Its snowballs pretty quickly doesn't it?
- If you make one app then there is only one code base, one place to make all code changes or add features. Its somewhat easy to maintain code wise.
- The bad side, well now you have to take care of every possible country specific scenario either within the app e.g. Localizations, currencies etc. or you have to get that information from your servers.
- There are ways to find out through apis from which country a user is connecting from without asking the user itself.
- In my opinion, creating one app is the way to go. It will save you lots of headaches down the road. But having said that I don't know how UBER or others big international players handle their country specific apps. Do they have one app or many. That I don't know.

[image]

Comment: You didn't get me... my app will be always one. Code is also one except products prices, which are coming from 3 db since it was created like this for Websites with their own domain like .com for US. and .AU for australia..... 

Only wanted to know can we upload different bundles for same app, so that american will see their data only. Advantage I saw was i dont want to open app in other countries.

we dont sell products other than 3 countries... so no use of displaying app to other countries.

Comment: I did get what you were saying and again the answer is yes. You can upload different bundles of the same app. The way you do it is you create 3 different project (same code), have three different apps on the app bundles that have 3 different app names on app store and they are all controlled by availability.